# Checking EnumDisplayDevices dwFlags

Tags: c++, windows

Currently I have a function and I want it to return the number of active monitors (by using EnumDisplayDevices).

```
...
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
    dd.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, numberofDeviceAdapters, &dd, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME))
    {
        if (dd.StateFlags == DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)
        {
            numberOfActiveMonitors++;
        }
        numberofDeviceAdapters++;

    }
    return numberOfActiveMonitors;
```

numberOfActiveMonitors is never increased, how do I correctly check the StateFlags of a DISPLAY_DEVICE?

Comment: Try `if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)`

Comment: Worked brilliantly, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read the MSDN documentation of the [`DISPLAY_DEVICE` data structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183569(v=vs.85).aspx), you will note that:

> **StateFlags**
>   Device state flags. It can be any reasonable combination of the following.
>   [...]

So, you should use the *binary `&` (bitwise AND) operator* to check if the desidered flag (in your case `DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE`) is set in the `StateFlags` data member of the aforementioned data structure.

e.g.:

```
// Your code: 
//   if (dd.StateFlags == DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)
//
// Change to (use binary AND & operator):
if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE)
{
    ...
}
```

This is a very common pattern in Win32/C++ programming for checking if a given binary flag is set in a `DWORD` containing several flags.

Comment: I tried to read all the information and knew it was binary but sometimes it's hard to find the specific thing. Anyways, thanks for the explanation (Just what I needed)!

Comment: You're welcome. Probably some minimal sample code on the MSDN documentation would have helped you.

Comment: Thanks for this answer @Mr.C64. Helped me a lot. I have a doubt regarding winAPI. Can you please answer my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65624377/enumdisplaydevices-giving-two-displays-even-though-i-have-one)