# Why does EnumDisplayDevices return so many results?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I have a Windows computer with an Nvidia card and an Intel card. Each GPU has one screen connected to it.

Then I use the following code to list all the display devices:

```c
DISPLAY_DEVICE lDevice;
lDevice.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);
int i = 0;
while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, i, &lDevice, EDD_GET_DEVICE_INTERFACE_NAME) != 0) {
    printf(
        "i: %d\n"
        "cb: %d\n"
        "DeviceName: %s\n"
        "DeviceString: %s\n"
        "StateFlags: %d\n"
        "DeviceID: %s\n"
        "DeviceKey: %s\n",
        i,
        lDevice.cb,
        lDevice.DeviceName,
        lDevice.DeviceString,
        lDevice.StateFlags,
        lDevice.DeviceID,
        lDevice.DeviceKey
    );
    i++;
}
```

This is the output:

```
i: 0
cb: 424
DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY1
DeviceString: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
StateFlags: 134217729
DeviceID: 
DeviceKey: \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{3C36D58A-5C95-11EB-ACEC-B083FE9A7909}\0000
i: 1
cb: 424
DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY2
DeviceString: Intel(R) HD Graphics 4600
StateFlags: 0
DeviceID: 
DeviceKey: \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{3C36D58A-5C95-11EB-ACEC-B083FE9A7909}\0001
i: 2
cb: 424
DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY3
DeviceString: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
StateFlags: 5
DeviceID: 
DeviceKey: \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{46FC15D3-C98C-11E9-ACCA-D1E7BCEC4649}\0000
i: 3
cb: 424
DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY4
DeviceString: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
StateFlags: 0
DeviceID: 
DeviceKey: \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{46FC15D3-C98C-11E9-ACCA-D1E7BCEC4649}\0001
i: 4
cb: 424
DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY5
DeviceString: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
StateFlags: 0
DeviceID: 
DeviceKey: \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{46FC15D3-C98C-11E9-ACCA-D1E7BCEC4649}\0002
i: 5
cb: 424
DeviceName: \\.\DISPLAY6
DeviceString: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1060 3GB
StateFlags: 0
DeviceID: 
DeviceKey: \Registry\Machine\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Video\{46FC15D3-C98C-11E9-ACCA-D1E7BCEC4649}\0003
```

I don't understand why there are 6 display devices, 2 for the Intel card and 4 for the Nvidia card. I think I'm probably missunderstanding the concept of display devices.

Here's the full code: https://gist.github.com/tuket/0cc2f9b77a4a6a82a72655941547e292

Comment: You need to learn the contents of StateFlags, which is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-display_devicea. Just print all flags for every device, and decide, how to filter the output. Probably, you need only DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE devices.

Comment: Just a guess... How many DP/HDMI ports do your graphic cards have? It might be 1 entry per connector.

Comment: @AlexF Thanks! I see only two of them (one for each card) have the ACTIVE flag set. What are the rest of the listed items then?

Comment: @Gerhardh Hey, that's good point. I don't know because I'm accessing that machine remotelly but I will try to find out. I have tried it in my laptop - it lists 3 displays, One of them active (I guess it's the integrated display). Once I connect an external monitor though HDMI, another one becomes active. I only have one HDMI port though, so I don't know what the third one is, maybe there is an internal connector that isn't exposed or something.

Comment: A display device is a software construct that's often specific to the driver (vendor). The interesting flags are DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP and DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/enumeration-and-display-control

Comment: Does this answer your question? [EnumDisplayDevices giving two Displays even though I have one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65624377/enumdisplaydevices-giving-two-displays-even-though-i-have-one)

Comment: @SongZhu-MSFT Nope, the comments here are more insightful, I think

Answer (score 2):

using StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP did seem to work for me.

demo https://github.com/rdp/enumdisplaydevices_console_app